# How do I separate subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
# Visualizations will be shown in the notebook.
%matplotlib inline


test_list= glob.glob('Outside_Test/*.jpg')
print(test_list)

print("test images shape")
for i in range(len(test_list)):
    print(test_list[i])

print("-----")
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5, figsize=(5,50))
fig.tight_layout() #  tried this too -> (pad=1.0)
for i in range(len(test_list)):
    image=np.array(mpimg.imread(test_list[i]))
    axs[i].imshow(image)
    axs[i].axis('off')
    
    _, test_file = os.path.split(test_list[i])
    print(test_file)
    print(image.shape)
    
    label_str = test_file[3:-4]  
    print(label_str)
    
    axs[i].set_title(label_str,fontsize=10)
```

However when I do this I get

[image]

in which the titles are one over the other.

How do I separate these subplots farther? I tried pad but did not work

EDIT: If I put the tight layout after the for I get

[image]

Comment: Did you try putting the `tight_layout` command after the `for` loop?

Comment: yes, and it is worse (see Edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your titles too long while the vertical dimension is to short. Try playing with `figsize`:

```
# roughly 1 x 5 aspect ratio here
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5, figsize=(10,50))

axs = axs.ravel()
for i in range(5):
    axs[i].imshow(np.arange(1024).reshape(32,32))

    # and also playing with `fontsize` here:
    axs[i].set_title('A very long long long title', fontsize=10)
    axs[i].axis('off')
    
fig.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]